# Dynamic forms angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am building a form on unknown length. The individual inputs can be of type text, file, textarea and maybe even select.

I have created a solution using *ngSwitch inside of *ngFor.

The json I am buidling the form on:

```
[{
    "name": "input1",
    "type": "text"
}, {
    "name": "input2",
    "type": "file"
}, {
    "name": "input3",
    "type": "text"
}]
```

and the code:

```
<div *ngFor="let part of myForm">   
    <div [ngSwitch]="part.type"> 
        <div *ngSwitchCase="'text'">
            <input/>
        </div>
        <div *ngSwitchCase="'file'">
            ....
        </div>
        ....
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem with this code is cannot specify the ngModel for the individual inputs, because if there were two inputs of type text, the ngModel would be duplicate.

Is there a way I could gather all of the values in something like an array? Would it be possible to create a solution using reactive forms?

Comment: I think the ReactiveForms is the way to go for this. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html

Comment: I implemented the solution using reactive forms, thanks for the hint. What should I do with this question?

Comment: Good question, I would just leave it for now. I would create an answer, but that would only be a link to the solution, which is frowned upon. Glad to hear you got this working!